# getting android. view.inflateException when I use zoomView for pageCurlView

Tags: android, zooming

please tell me how can i remove the exception. or give me idea to implement zoom view with curlview.....

my xml file is like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/relat">
<com.example.image.ZoomView
 >

<com.example.image.PageCurlView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dcgpagecurlPageCurlView1"
    >
</com.example.image.PageCurlView>
```

my java file is
    package com.example.image;

```
public class StandaloneExample extends Activity {

Button bt;LinearLayout lr;
/** Decoded bitmap image */
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private ZoomView zoomview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.standalone_example);

            View v1 = ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.standalone_example, null, false);
            v1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


            zoomview.addView(v1);

            lr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.relat);
            lr.addView(zoomview);  


}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    System.gc();
    finish();
}


public void lockOrientationLandscape() {
    lockOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}


public void lockOrientationPortrait() {
    lockOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}


public void lockOrientation( int orientation ) {
    setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
}
```

}

i have implemented zoomView.java as described in [a link](https://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/)

pagecurlview.java class is

```
public class PageCurlView extends View {


private final static String TAG = "PageCurlView";


private Paint mTextPaint;
private TextPaint mTextPaintShadow;

private int mCurlSpeed;

private int mUpdateRate;


private int mInitialEdgeOffset;


private int mCurlMode;

public static final int CURLMODE_SIMPLE = 0;


public static final int CURLMODE_DYNAMIC = 1;


private boolean bEnableDebugMode = false;


private WeakReference<Context> mContext;


private FlipAnimationHandler mAnimationHandler;


private float mFlipRadius;

private Vector2D mMovement;
private Vector2D mFinger;


private Vector2D mOldMovement;

private Paint mCurlEdgePaint;


private Vector2D mA, mB, mC, mD, mE, mF, mOldF, mOrigin;

private int mCurrentLeft, mCurrentTop;


private boolean bViewDrawn;


private boolean bFlipRight;


private boolean bFlipping;

private boolean bUserMoves;


private boolean bBlockTouchInput = false;


private boolean bEnableInputAfterDraw = false;


private Bitmap mForeground;


private Bitmap mBackground;


private ArrayList<Bitmap> mPages;


private int mIndex = 0;

private class Vector2D
{
    public float x,y;
    public Vector2D(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "("+this.x+","+this.y+")";
    }

     public float length() {
         return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
     }

     public float lengthSquared() {
             return (x * x) + (y * y);
     }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Vector2D) {
            Vector2D p = (Vector2D) o;
            return p.x == x && p.y == y;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Vector2D reverse() {
        return new Vector2D(-x,-y);
    }

    public Vector2D sum(Vector2D b) {
        return new Vector2D(x+b.x,y+b.y);
    }

    public Vector2D sub(Vector2D b) {
        return new Vector2D(x-b.x,y-b.y);
    }       

    public float dot(Vector2D vec) {
        return (x * vec.x) + (y * vec.y);
    }

    public float cross(Vector2D a, Vector2D b) {
            return a.cross(b);
    }

    public float cross(Vector2D vec) {
            return x * vec.y - y * vec.x;
    }

    public float distanceSquared(Vector2D other) {
        float dx = other.x - x;
        float dy = other.y - y;

        return (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
    }

    public float distance(Vector2D other) {
            return (float) Math.sqrt(distanceSquared(other));
    }

    public float dotProduct(Vector2D other) {
        return other.x * x + other.y * y;
    }

    public Vector2D normalize() {
        float magnitude = (float) Math.sqrt(dotProduct(this));
        return new Vector2D(x / magnitude, y / magnitude);
    }

    public Vector2D mult(float scalar) {
            return new Vector2D(x*scalar,y*scalar);
    }
}


class FlipAnimationHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        PageCurlView.this.FlipAnimationStep();
    }

    public void sleep(long millis) {
        this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), millis);
    }
}

public PageCurlView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
    ResetClipEdge();
}

public PageCurlView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);

    // Get the data from the XML AttributeSet
    {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PageCurlView);

        // Get data
        bEnableDebugMode = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PageCurlView_enableDebugMode, bEnableDebugMode);
        mCurlSpeed = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_curlSpeed, mCurlSpeed);
        mUpdateRate = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_updateRate, mUpdateRate);
        mInitialEdgeOffset = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_initialEdgeOffset, mInitialEdgeOffset);
        mCurlMode = a.getInt(R.styleable.PageCurlView_curlMode, mCurlMode);

        Log.i(TAG, "mCurlSpeed: " + mCurlSpeed);
        Log.i(TAG, "mUpdateRate: " + mUpdateRate);
        Log.i(TAG, "mInitialEdgeOffset: " + mInitialEdgeOffset);
        Log.i(TAG, "mCurlMode: " + mCurlMode);

        // recycle object (so it can be used by others)
        a.recycle();
    }

    ResetClipEdge();
}


private final void init(Context context) {
    // Foreground text paint
    mTextPaint = new Paint();
    mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(16);
    mTextPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);

    // The shadow
    mTextPaintShadow = new TextPaint();
    mTextPaintShadow.setAntiAlias(true);
    mTextPaintShadow.setTextSize(16);
    mTextPaintShadow.setColor(0x00000000);

    // Cache the context
    mContext = new WeakReference<Context>(context);

    // Base padding
    setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

    // The focus flags are needed
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    mMovement =  new Vector2D(0,0);
    mFinger = new Vector2D(0,0);
    mOldMovement = new Vector2D(0,0);

    // Create our curl animation handler
    mAnimationHandler = new FlipAnimationHandler();

    // Create our edge paint
    mCurlEdgePaint = new Paint();
    mCurlEdgePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mCurlEdgePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mCurlEdgePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mCurlEdgePaint.setShadowLayer(10, -5, 5, 0x99000000);

    // Set the default props, those come from an XML :D
    mCurlSpeed = 30;
    mUpdateRate = 33;
    mInitialEdgeOffset = 20;
    mCurlMode = 1;

    // LEGACY PAGE HANDLING!

    // Create pages
    mPages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.princess));
    mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.temp));

    // Create some sample images
    mForeground = mPages.get(0);
    mBackground = mPages.get(1);
}


public void ResetClipEdge()
{
    // Set our base movement
    mMovement.x = mInitialEdgeOffset;
    mMovement.y = mInitialEdgeOffset;       
    mOldMovement.x = 0;
    mOldMovement.y = 0;     

    // Now set the points
    // TODO: OK, those points MUST come from our measures and
    // the actual bounds of the view!
    mA = new Vector2D(mInitialEdgeOffset, 0);
    mB = new Vector2D(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    mC = new Vector2D(this.getWidth(), 0);
    mD = new Vector2D(0, 0);
    mE = new Vector2D(0, 0);
    mF = new Vector2D(0, 0);        
    mOldF = new Vector2D(0, 0);

    // The movement origin point
    mOrigin = new Vector2D(this.getWidth(), 0);
}

private Context GetContext() {
    return mContext.get();
}

public boolean IsCurlModeDynamic()
{
    return mCurlMode == CURLMODE_DYNAMIC;
}


public void SetCurlSpeed(int curlSpeed)
{
    if ( curlSpeed < 1 )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("curlSpeed must be greated than 0");
    mCurlSpeed = curlSpeed;
}

public int GetCurlSpeed()
{
    return mCurlSpeed;
}

public void SetUpdateRate(int updateRate)
{
    if ( updateRate < 1 )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("updateRate must be greated than 0");
    mUpdateRate = updateRate;
}


public int GetUpdateRate()
{
    return mUpdateRate;
}


public void SetInitialEdgeOffset(int initialEdgeOffset)
{
    if ( initialEdgeOffset < 0 )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("initialEdgeOffset can not negative");
    mInitialEdgeOffset = initialEdgeOffset;
}


public int GetInitialEdgeOffset()
{
    return mInitialEdgeOffset;
}


public void SetCurlMode(int curlMode)
{
    if ( curlMode != CURLMODE_SIMPLE &&
         curlMode != CURLMODE_DYNAMIC )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid curlMode");
    mCurlMode = curlMode;
}



public int GetCurlMode()
{
    return mCurlMode;
}


public void SetEnableDebugMode(boolean bFlag)
{
    bEnableDebugMode = bFlag;
}

public boolean IsDebugModeEnabled()
{
    return bEnableDebugMode;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int finalWidth, finalHeight;
    finalWidth = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
    finalHeight = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(finalWidth, finalHeight);
}

private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the text
        result = specSize;
    }

    return result;
}

private int measureHeight(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
        result = specSize;
    }
    return result;
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!bBlockTouchInput) {

        // Get our finger position
        mFinger.x = event.getX();
        mFinger.y = event.getY();
        int width = getWidth();

        // Depending on the action do what we need to
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:               
            mOldMovement.x = mFinger.x;
            mOldMovement.y = mFinger.y;

            // If we moved over the half of the display flip to next
            if (mOldMovement.x > (width >> 1)) {
                mMovement.x = mInitialEdgeOffset;
                mMovement.y = mInitialEdgeOffset;

                // Set the right movement flag
                bFlipRight = true;
            } else {
                // Set the left movement flag
                bFlipRight = false;

                // go to next previous page
                previousView();

                // Set new movement
                mMovement.x = IsCurlModeDynamic()?width<<1:width;
                mMovement.y = mInitialEdgeOffset;
            }

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:             
            bUserMoves=false;
            bFlipping=true;
            FlipAnimationStep();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            bUserMoves=true;

            // Get movement
            mMovement.x -= mFinger.x - mOldMovement.x;
            mMovement.y -= mFinger.y - mOldMovement.y;
            mMovement = CapMovement(mMovement, true);

            // Make sure the y value get's locked at a nice level
            if ( mMovement.y  <= 1 )
                mMovement.y = 1;

            // Get movement direction
            if (mFinger.x < mOldMovement.x ) {
                bFlipRight = true;
            } else {
                bFlipRight = false;
            }

            // Save old movement values
            mOldMovement.x  = mFinger.x;
            mOldMovement.y  = mFinger.y;

            // Force a new draw call
            DoPageCurl();
            this.invalidate();
            break;
        }

    }

    // TODO: Only consume event if we need to.
    return true;
}


private Vector2D CapMovement(Vector2D point, boolean bMaintainMoveDir)
{
    // Make sure we never ever move too much
    if (point.distance(mOrigin) > mFlipRadius)
    {
        if ( bMaintainMoveDir )
        {
            // Maintain the direction
            point = mOrigin.sum(point.sub(mOrigin).normalize().mult(mFlipRadius));
        }
        else
        {
            // Change direction
            if ( point.x > (mOrigin.x+mFlipRadius))
                point.x = (mOrigin.x+mFlipRadius);
            else if ( point.x < (mOrigin.x-mFlipRadius) )
                point.x = (mOrigin.x-mFlipRadius);
            point.y = (float) (Math.sin(Math.acos(Math.abs(point.x-mOrigin.x)/mFlipRadius))*mFlipRadius);
        }
    }
    return point;
}


public void FlipAnimationStep() {
    if ( !bFlipping )
        return;

    int width = getWidth();

    // No input when flipping
    bBlockTouchInput = true;

    // Handle speed
    float curlSpeed = mCurlSpeed;
    if ( !bFlipRight )
        curlSpeed *= -1;

    // Move us
    mMovement.x += curlSpeed;
    mMovement = CapMovement(mMovement, false);

    // Create values
    DoPageCurl();

    // Check for endings :D
    if (mA.x < 1 || mA.x > width - 1) {
        bFlipping = false;
        if (bFlipRight) {
            //SwapViews();
            nextView();
        } 
        ResetClipEdge();

        // Create values
        DoPageCurl();

        // Enable touch input after the next draw event
        bEnableInputAfterDraw = true;
    }
    else
    {
        mAnimationHandler.sleep(mUpdateRate);
    }

    // Force a new draw call
    this.invalidate();
}


private void DoPageCurl()
{
    if(bFlipping){
        if ( IsCurlModeDynamic() )
            doDynamicCurl();
        else
            doSimpleCurl();

    } else {
        if ( IsCurlModeDynamic() )
            doDynamicCurl();
        else
            doSimpleCurl();
    }
}


private void doSimpleCurl() {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    // Calculate point A
    mA.x = width - mMovement.x;
    mA.y = height;

    // Calculate point D
    mD.x = 0;
    mD.y = 0;
    if (mA.x > width / 2) {
        mD.x = width;
        mD.y = height - (width - mA.x) * height / mA.x;
    } else {
        mD.x = 2 * mA.x;
        mD.y = 0;
    }


    double angle = Math.atan((height - mD.y) / (mD.x + mMovement.x - width));
    double _cos = Math.cos(2 * angle);
    double _sin = Math.sin(2 * angle);


    mF.x = (float) (width - mMovement.x + _cos * mMovement.x);
    mF.y = (float) (height - _sin * mMovement.x);

    // If the x position of A is above half of the page we are still not
    // folding the upper-right edge and so E and D are equal.
    if (mA.x > width / 2) {
        mE.x = mD.x;
        mE.y = mD.y;
    }
    else
    {
        // So get E
        mE.x = (float) (mD.x + _cos * (width - mD.x));
        mE.y = (float) -(_sin * (width - mD.x));
    }
}


private void doDynamicCurl() {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();


    mF.x = width - mMovement.x+0.1f;
    mF.y = height - mMovement.y+0.1f;


    if(mA.x==0) {
        mF.x= Math.min(mF.x, mOldF.x);
        mF.y= Math.max(mF.y, mOldF.y);
    }

    // Get diffs
    float deltaX = width-mF.x;
    float deltaY = height-mF.y;

    float BH = (float) (Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY) / 2);
    double tangAlpha = deltaY / deltaX;
    double alpha = Math.atan(deltaY / deltaX);
    double _cos = Math.cos(alpha);
    double _sin = Math.sin(alpha);

    mA.x = (float) (width - (BH / _cos));
    mA.y = height;

    mD.y = (float) (height - (BH / _sin));
    mD.x = width;

    mA.x = Math.max(0,mA.x);
    if(mA.x==0) {
        mOldF.x = mF.x;
        mOldF.y = mF.y;
    }

    // Get W
    mE.x = mD.x;
    mE.y = mD.y;

    // Correct
    if (mD.y < 0) {
        mD.x = width + (float) (tangAlpha * mD.y);
        mE.y = 0;
        mE.x = width + (float) (Math.tan(2 * alpha) * mD.y);
    }
}


@Deprecated
private void SwapViews() {
    Bitmap temp = mForeground;
    mForeground = mBackground;
    mBackground = temp;
}


private void nextView() {
    int foreIndex = mIndex + 1;
    if(foreIndex >= mPages.size()) {
        foreIndex = 0;
    }
    int backIndex = foreIndex + 1;
    if(backIndex >= mPages.size()) {
        backIndex = 0;
    }
    mIndex = foreIndex;
    setViews(foreIndex, backIndex);
}


private void previousView() {
    int backIndex = mIndex;
    int foreIndex = backIndex - 1;
    if(foreIndex < 0) {
        foreIndex = mPages.size()-1;
    }
    mIndex = foreIndex;
    setViews(foreIndex, backIndex);
}

private void setViews(int foreground, int background) {
    mForeground = mPages.get(foreground);
    mBackground = mPages.get(background);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    mCurrentLeft = getLeft();
    mCurrentTop = getTop();

    if ( !bViewDrawn ) {
        bViewDrawn = true;
        onFirstDrawEvent(canvas);
    }

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);


    Rect rect = new Rect();
    rect.left = 0;
    rect.top = 0;
    rect.bottom = getHeight();
    rect.right = getWidth();

    // First Page render
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    // Draw our elements
    drawForeground(canvas, rect, paint);
    drawBackground(canvas, rect, paint);
    drawCurlEdge(canvas);

    // Draw any debug info once we are done
    if ( bEnableDebugMode )
        drawDebug(canvas);

    // Check if we can re-enable input
    if ( bEnableInputAfterDraw )
    {
        bBlockTouchInput = false;
        bEnableInputAfterDraw = false;
    }

    // Restore canvas
    //canvas.restore();
}


protected void onFirstDrawEvent(Canvas canvas) {

    mFlipRadius = getWidth();

    ResetClipEdge();
    DoPageCurl();
}

private void drawForeground( Canvas canvas, Rect rect, Paint paint ) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mForeground, null, rect, paint);

    // Draw the page number (first page is 1 in real life :D 
    // there is no page number 0 hehe)
    drawPageNum(canvas, mIndex);
}


private Path createBackgroundPath() {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(mA.x, mA.y);
    path.lineTo(mB.x, mB.y);
    path.lineTo(mC.x, mC.y);
    path.lineTo(mD.x, mD.y);
    path.lineTo(mA.x, mA.y);
    return path;
}

private void drawBackground( Canvas canvas, Rect rect, Paint paint ) {
    Path mask = createBackgroundPath();

    // Save current canvas so we do not mess it up
    canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(mask);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, null, rect, paint);

    // Draw the page number (first page is 1 in real life :D 
    // there is no page number 0 hehe)
    drawPageNum(canvas, mIndex);

    canvas.restore();
}


private Path createCurlEdgePath() {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(mA.x, mA.y);
    path.lineTo(mD.x, mD.y);
    path.lineTo(mE.x, mE.y);
    path.lineTo(mF.x, mF.y);
    path.lineTo(mA.x, mA.y);
    return path;
}


private void drawCurlEdge( Canvas canvas )
{
    Path path = createCurlEdgePath();
    canvas.drawPath(path, mCurlEdgePaint);
}


private void drawPageNum(Canvas canvas, int pageNum)
{
    mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    String pageNumText = "- "+pageNum+" -";
    drawCentered(canvas, pageNumText,canvas.getHeight()-mTextPaint.getTextSize()-5,mTextPaint,mTextPaintShadow);
}

public static void drawTextShadowed(Canvas canvas, String text, float x, float y, Paint textPain, Paint shadowPaint) {
    canvas.drawText(text, x-1, y, shadowPaint);
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y+1, shadowPaint);
    canvas.drawText(text, x+1, y, shadowPaint);
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y-1, shadowPaint);     
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, textPain);
}


public static void drawCentered(Canvas canvas, String text, float y, Paint textPain, Paint shadowPaint)
{
    float posx = (canvas.getWidth() - textPain.measureText(text))/2;
    drawTextShadowed(canvas, text, posx, y, textPain, shadowPaint);
}

private void drawDebug(Canvas canvas)
{
    float posX = 10;
    float posY = 20;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);        
    canvas.drawCircle(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, getWidth(), paint);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);      
    canvas.drawCircle(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, getWidth(), paint);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawLine(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, mMovement.x, mMovement.y, paint);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawLine(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, mMovement.x, mMovement.y, paint);

    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas,"A",mA,Color.RED,posX,posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas,"B",mB,Color.GREEN,posX,posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas,"C",mC,Color.BLUE,posX,posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas,"D",mD,Color.CYAN,posX,posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas,"E",mE,Color.YELLOW,posX,posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas,"F",mF,Color.LTGRAY,posX,posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas,"Mov",mMovement,Color.DKGRAY,posX,posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas,"Origin",mOrigin,Color.MAGENTA,posX,posY);
    posY = debugDrawPoint(canvas,"Finger",mFinger,Color.GREEN,posX,posY);

    }

private float debugDrawPoint(Canvas canvas, String name, Vector2D point, int color, float posX, float posY) {   
    return debugDrawPoint(canvas,name+" "+point.toString(),point.x, point.y, color, posX, posY);
}

private float debugDrawPoint(Canvas canvas, String name, float X, float Y, int color, float posX, float posY) {
    mTextPaint.setColor(color);
    drawTextShadowed(canvas,name,posX , posY, mTextPaint,mTextPaintShadow);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setColor(color);  
    canvas.drawPoint(X, Y, paint);
    return posY+15;
}
```

}

Comment: pls give me some valid links to implement zooming and paning of views

Comment: @user1954282 : heave found solution for this yet? please let me know if you found.

Comment: @Biginner yes finally i went for an odd solution.I just navigated to an imageview from flipview(on touch at specific points) and included zoom features there.